# Compare a dateRange with other continous dates in another list to get adjacent ranges relative to the list compared

Tags: java

e.g.

There is a date range from Feb9 thru May 19 in an interval. There is another list of effective dates in a Map for key values like  as of this date this object is returned (Jan 1, Object x), (Feb 1, Object y), (March 1, Object z) (April 1, Object a) (May 1, Object u), (June1, Object n) etc.

The algorithm need is to take the date range of Feb1 thru June19 and to get adjacent dates for the effective date ranges e.g.

the method would be

TreeMapreturnTemporalAdjacentInterval(Interval when)

result should be Treemap sorted by adjacent interval with (Feb9-March1, Object y) (March1-April1, Object z) (April1-May1, Object a) (May1-May19, Object u)

This is like martin fowlers temporal collection however more of a temporal adjacent interval retrieval. Language is Java joda-time Interval is suggested use for the returned intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample class inspired by Martin Fowlers [temporal object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/TemporalObject.html) with the method implementation for returning the adjacent intervals.

```
public HashMap<Interval, Object> getAdjacentIntervals(Interval when)
```

This shows an algorithm with a certain complexity. Any input on a faster version. Unit tests are below to show the tests for the object and document better context

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.Interval;

public class TemporalCollection {

private Map<DateTime, Object> contents = new HashMap<DateTime, Object>();

private List<DateTime> _milestoneCache;

public Object get(DateTime when) {
    /** returns the value that was effective on the given date */
    Iterator<DateTime> it = milestones().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        DateTime thisDate = it.next();
        if (thisDate.isBefore(when) || thisDate.equals(when))
            return contents.get(thisDate);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no records that early");
}

public HashMap<Interval, Object> getAdjacentIntervals(Interval when) {
    // start to get the start date object
    DateTime startDate = when.getStart();
    DateTime endDate = when.getEnd();
    HashMap<Interval, Object> result = new HashMap<Interval, Object>();
    Iterator<DateTime> it = milestones().iterator();

    DateTime endDateToCompare = endDate;
    DateTime startDateToCompare = startDate;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        DateTime thisDate = it.next();
        if (thisDate.isBefore(endDateToCompare)
                || thisDate.equals(endDateToCompare)) {
            Interval adjacentIntervalPart;
            if (thisDate.isAfter(startDateToCompare) &&  !thisDate.equals(endDateToCompare)) {
                // we have hit upper end of the range
                // upper end of the adjacent interval is as follows
                adjacentIntervalPart = new Interval(thisDate,
                        endDateToCompare);

                result.put(adjacentIntervalPart, contents.get(thisDate));

                endDateToCompare = endDateToCompare.minus(new Duration(
                        thisDate, endDateToCompare));

            } else {


                // we have reached the last range
               adjacentIntervalPart = new Interval(startDate, endDateToCompare);
               result.put(adjacentIntervalPart, contents.get(thisDate));

               return result;
            }
        }

    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no records that early for an Interval");

}

public void put(DateTime at, Object item) {
    /** the item is valid and effective from the supplied date onwards */
    contents.put(at, item);
    clearMilestoneCache();
}

private List<DateTime> milestones() {
    /**
     * a list of all the dates where the value changed, returned in order
     * latest first
     */
    if (_milestoneCache == null)
        calculateMilestones();
    return _milestoneCache;
}

private void calculateMilestones() {
    _milestoneCache = new ArrayList<DateTime>(contents.size());
    _milestoneCache.addAll(contents.keySet());
    Collections.sort(_milestoneCache, Collections.reverseOrder());
}

private void clearMilestoneCache() {
    _milestoneCache = null;
}

}
```

The Unit test class is as follows

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.joda.money.Money;
import org.joda.time.DateMidnight;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.Interval;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.vrntmgr.server.utils.StringUtils;

public class TemporalCollectionTest {

TemporalCollection rates;

@Before
public void setup() {
    rates = new TemporalCollection();
    rates.put(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 1).toDateTime(),
            Money.parse("USD 900"));
    rates.put(new DateMidnight(2010, 2, 1).toDateTime(),
            Money.parse("USD 1000"));
    rates.put(new DateMidnight(2010, 3, 1).toDateTime(),
            Money.parse("USD 2000"));
}

@Test
public void testTemporalRetreival() {
    Interval intrvl = new Interval(new DateMidnight(2010, 1, 15),
            new DateMidnight(2010, 3, 15));

    HashMap<Interval, Object> myMap = rates.getAdjacentIntervals(intrvl);
    // System.out.println(StringUtils.toString(myMap.keySet()));


    Iterator<Interval> it = myMap.keySet().iterator();
    Assert.assertEquals(it.next(),new Interval(new DateMidnight(2010,3,1), new DateMidnight(2010,3,15)));
    Assert.assertEquals(it.next(),new Interval(new DateMidnight(2010,2,1), new DateMidnight(2010,3,1)));
    Assert.assertEquals(it.next(),new Interval(new DateMidnight(2010,1,15), new DateMidnight(2010,2,1)));
}

@Test 
public void testEndDayAfterRange() {


    Interval intrvl = new Interval(new DateMidnight(2010,1,15), new DateMidnight(2010, 2, 1));

    HashMap<Interval, Object> myMap =  rates.getAdjacentIntervals(intrvl);


    Iterator<Interval> it = myMap.keySet().iterator();
    Interval res = it.next();
    Assert.assertEquals(res,new Interval(new DateMidnight(2010,1,15), new DateMidnight(2010,2,1)));

    System.out.println("days are" + Days.daysIn(res));

}


}
```